# Cannot load viper-mode in Emacs24

Tags: osx-lion, emacs

Every time I try to load viper-mode in Emacs24 using <kbd>M-x viper-mode</kbd>, I get error

```
Wrong type argument: symbolp, (quote 3)
```

I have observed it happens when I try to load viper-mode for the after opening Emacs or after I have issued <kbd>M-x viper-go-away</kbd>

So once I get this error and run the same command again, viper-mode loads successfully.

When I use toggle-viper-mode to turn it off, viper-mode goes away successfully. But when I try to turn it back on using `toggle-viper-mode` again, I get the above stated error. I have to use `viper-go-away` and then <kbd>M-x viper-mode</kbd> twice to get it back working.

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: The `kbd` markup is usually used to denote (single) keyboard keys ;)

Comment: If you want to, you can debug the error by evaluating `(setq debug-on-error t)` before the error happens, but it may help to have the functions in question loaded in uncompiled (.el) form first.  You can do that by visiting the source file(s) and typing `M-x eval-current-buffer RET` in each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [Fran](https://superuser.com/questions/432513/cannot-load-viper-mode-in-emacs24/433082#comment498609_432513) comment, I was able to resolve the problem.

I placed, `(setq debug-on-error t)` in scratch file and evaluated it. Then I loaded the viper-mode. I got a 14 line output. The relevant part is

> Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument symbolp (quote 3))
>     (setq viper-expert-level (quote 3) (quote 3) (quote 3) (quote 3) (quote 3) (quote 5) (quote 3) (quote 3) (quote 3) (quote 5) (quote 3))
>     eval-buffer(# nil "/Users/andy/.viper" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 60
>     load-with-code-conversion("/Users/andy/.viper" "/Users/andy/.viper" nil nil)                                                                                                   load("~/.viper")

I didn't know there is a .viper file present in home directory. For some unknown reason it's first line was

> (setq viper-expert-level  '3 '3 '3 '3 '3 '5 '3 '3 '3 '5 '3)
>   (setq viper-inhibit-startup-message 't)

I edited the first line and the problem got solved:

> (setq viper-expert-level  '3)